# Using class Objects and its properties in Java Collections

Tags: java, collections, hashmap, linkedhashmap

I have a Class `Class1` with 3 properties (`prop1`, `prop2`, `prop3`).
I have another Class Class2 with a Hashmap hashMap1.
I am using Class1 object in hashMap1 and inserting a value for `prop1`, `prop2`, `prop3`.

Class1

```
public class Class1
{
    private String Prop1;
    private String Prop2;
    private int Prop3;

    public Class1(String Prop1, String Prop2, int Prop3)
    {
        this.Prop1= Prop1;
        this.Prop2= Prop2;
        this.Prop3= Prop3;
    }
}
```

Class2

```
public class Class2
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        HashMap<String, Class1> hashMap1= new LinkedHashMap<>(); 

        hashMap1.put("01" , new Class1("Prop1a","Prop2a", 101));
        hashMap1.put("02" , new Class1("Prop1a","Prop2b", 202));
        hashMap1.put("03" , new Class1("Prop1b","Prop2a", 303));    
    }
}
```

I am trying to figure out, how can I print all the Listings from Collections where `Prop1 = "Prop1a"` OR `Prop2 = "Prop2a"`?
I hope that make sense.

Please let me know if there is a better way I can implement this.

Comment: Obviously you will need a getter on `Class1` so you can retrieve those values.

Comment: Note: you have a syntax error.  The map is assigned to `HashMap1` but you try to use `hashMap1`.

Comment: Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Old school (simple, works with all versions of Java) use a loop.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
  HashMap<String, Class1> hashMap1= new LinkedHashMap<String, Class1>(); 

    hashMap1.put("01" , new Class1("Prop1a","Prop2a", 101));
    hashMap1.put("02" , new Class1("Prop1a","Prop2b", 202));
    hashMap1.put("03" , new Class1("Prop1b","Prop2a", 303));

    for( Class1 c : hashMap1.values() ) {
       if( c.getProp1().equals( "Prop1a" ) || c.getProp2().equals( "Prop2a" ) )
          System.out.println( c );
    }
}
```

Note you of course need getters in `Class1`, and an overridden `toString` is useful.

```
class Class1
{
    private String Prop1;
    private String Prop2;
    private int Prop3;

   public String getProp1() {
      return Prop1;
   }

   public String getProp2() {
      return Prop2;
   }

   public int getProp3() {
      return Prop3;
   }

    public Class1(String Prop1, String Prop2, int Prop3)
    {
        this.Prop1= Prop1;
        this.Prop2= Prop2;
        this.Prop3= Prop3;
    }

   @Override
   public String toString() {
      return "Class1{" + "Prop1=" + Prop1 + ", Prop2=" + Prop2 + ", Prop3=" + Prop3 + '}';
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get list of `Class1` with specific properties it can be done by stream api also:

```
Predicate<Class1> prop1Predicate = class1 -> class1.getProp1().equals("Prop1a");
Predicate<Class1> prop2Predicate = class1 -> class1.getProp2().equals("Prop2a");

List<Class1> list = hashMap1.values().stream()
        .filter(prop1Predicate.or(prop2Predicate))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());  // or .forEach(System.out::println); to print (without return value)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create getters in Class1 and ideally also override toString() method to print Class1 in your desired way. Then you can do something like this:

```
 for (Map.Entry<String, Class1> entry : hashMap1.entrySet()) {
        Class1 value = entry.getValue();
        if (value.getProp1().equals("Prop1a") || value.getProp2().equals("Prop2a")) {
             System.out.println(value);
        }
 }
```

I didn't test the code, let me know in comments if it doesn't work.

Comment: When you are not using the key, there is no need to iterate over the `entrySet()`. Just iterate over the values, i.e. `for(Class1 value: hashMap1.values()) { … }`

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to iterate over your map's values, select those that match your criteria and print them. One way to do this is with a stream:

```
hashMap1.entrySet()
        .stream()
        .filter(c1 -> c1.getProp1().equals("Prop1a") || c1.getProp2.equals("Prop2a"))
        .forEach(c1 -> System.out.println(c1));
```

You'll need to implement the basic getters and `toString()` for `Class1`.